# Proper Display of QueryException Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

Hi I'm thinking to how properly display a duplicate entry. I don't have any idea on how to display it properly.

```
public function store($request){

    try{

        $this->modelName->create( $request );

        return [
            'success' => true
        ];
    }
    catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){

        return [
            'success' => false,
            'error' => $e->getMessage()
        ];
    }

}
```

I need to manipulate the $e->getMessage(). Here is the an awful display of the the duplicate entry. [image]

Comment: Use can use unique() in validate function.

Comment: $this->validate($request, [
            'email'     => 'email|max:255|unique:users',
        ]);

Comment: Yeah, I have tried it but triggers and error of queryException that is why I sorted to that.

Comment: I found the errors now why it issue a queryexception rather than an error came from validation. Thanks.